# IllegalStateException - Fragment no longer exists

Tags: android, android-fragments, illegalstateexception

I see IllegalStateException in Google-Play Console, which I can't reproduce.

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3253)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3349)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100 (ActivityThread.java:221)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1794)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:158)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7224)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.getFragment (FragmentManager.java:668)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:999)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1252)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1234)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate (FragmentManager.java:2041)
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate (Fragment.java:1964)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1029)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1252)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1234)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate (FragmentManager.java:2041)
      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate (Fragment.java:1964)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1029)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1252)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1234)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreate (FragmentManager.java:2041)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate (FragmentController.java:163)
      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:331)
      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java:85)
      at com.example.eliran.forum.RootActivity.onCreate (RootActivity.java:53)
      at com.example.eliran.forum.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:58)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6876)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3206)
```

I have activity with NavigationView which contains fragments.

I suspect that this exception happens when the user press on the back button and a function that contains the following code is called:

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

Google-Play console doesn't display this, but this is the exception error:

```
    throwException(new IllegalStateException("Fragment no longer exists for key "
            + key + ": index " + index));
```

Comment: In NavigationView  try to replace fragment, but not add fragment. if you are replacing fragment, then do not use addToBackStack().

Comment: I replace fragment and and then fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

Comment: use getFragmentManager() instead

Comment: @Mr.AF what's the difference? and how it will solve it?

Comment: @ٍEliran i think getSupportFragmentManager used for android.support.v4.app

Comment: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

Comment: @Mr.AF I use android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager

Comment: change it for a test then see if it solved??

Comment: @Mr.AF I don't know how to reproduce this issue then I cant test it.

Comment: Do you use `setTargetFragment()` somewhere?

Comment: @azizbekian yes, in one of the fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably use setTargetFragment() somewhere in your code.
Just avoid using it.
Instead, communicate between the fragemnts via callback and listener like this:
In fragmentDialog -

protected OnRemovedTopicListener callback = null;

```
public interface OnRemovedTopicListener {
    public abstract void onTopicRemoved(int position);
}

public void setOnRemovedTopicListener(OnRemovedTopicListener l){
    callback = l;
}
```

and using the callback - 
callback.onTopicRemoved(position);

In the parent fragment -

```
    dialogFragment.setOnRemovedTopicListener(new ForumTopicDialogFragment.OnRemovedTopicListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTopicRemoved(int position) {
            // you code here
        }
    });
```